# Add a value to CustomPapers' plist using Terminal

Tags: terminal, printing

I'm trying to add a printer to CustomPapers' `.plist` using this terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.print.custompapers.plist 165x165 -dict-add <bottom>0</bottom><custom>1</custom><height>467.71653555</height><id>'165x165'</id><left>0</left><name>'165x165'</name><printer> </printer><right>0</right><top>0</top><width>467.71653555</width>
```

Please can someone suggest where I've gone wrong with this and if a dictionary item exists with the key "165x165" that it should not add the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to quote the value, remove `-dict-add`, and use for example `<key>name</key><string>165x165</string>` instead of `<name>165x165</name>`:

`defaults write com.apple.print.custompapers 165x165 '<dict><key>bottom</key><real>0</real><key>custom</key><true/><key>height</key><real>467.71653555</real><key>id</key><string>165x165</string><key>left</key><real>0</real><key>name</key><string>165x165</string><key>printer</key><string> </string><key>right</key><real>0</real><key>top</key><real>0</real><key>width</key><real>467.71653555</real></dict>'`

This checks if the key exists:

`if defaults read com.apple.print.custompapers 165x165 &> /dev/null; then echo 'the key exists'; fi`